# VB.NET MDB creating a table command and Autonumber type

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

i am using the following command to create a table in an mdb database, it works fine when i remove the autonumber type

```
"CREATE TABLE pxs(sid Autonumber , Adress Text , Port Text, user Text, pass Text, sreq Integer, freq Integer)"
```

so how should i define an id column as autonumber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
CREATE TABLE pxs(sid counter primary key, ...
```

Note that `user` is a reserved word, so you might like to use some other name.